# Who are the demons killed by Lord Balarama?

Tags: balarama

What is the list of demons killed by Lord Balarama?

Comment: List like questions would be too broad..

Comment: @YDS No it's not

Comment: The question is not too broad. we can compile the list easily.

Comment: @YDS We have a plenty of questions like this where an OP asks a list of Rakshasas killed by someone else. Yes, list questions are too broad because we have to search everywhere but we allowed similar questions in the past,